# How to make a query to get all contributions from a certain donor?

Tags: openfec

In https://api.open.fec.gov/v1/schedules/schedule_a/
the maximum results per query are 100, e.g. the following [large FEC query](https://api.open.fec.gov/v1/schedules/schedule_a/?api_key=KEYKEYKEY&min_date=12%2F12%2F1999&sort_nulls_large=true&contributor_name=ab%2C%20lin%2C&per_page=101) will result in:

```
{
  "message": "Parameter \"per_page\" must be between 1 and 100",
  "status": 422
}
```

If I want to get *all* contributions from a certain donor, how should I formulate my query?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one query, you have to page through. Use the `&page=N` argument where N is page of results you want.